# Cordova shows an warning as " THREAD WARNING: [Your function] took [n] ms. " in iOS

Tags: ios, thread-safety, cordova-plugins, background-thread, cordova-3.8.0

```
 "THREAD WARNING: ['Console'] took '81.661865' ms. Plugin should use a  background thread."
```

While running **iOS Phonegap** project. Similarly for some of the remaining plugins like geolocation and filesystem.

As I am new to Phonegap ,can please anyone tell me how can I run the plugin on background thread.

I have checked [this](https://github.com/Moodstocks/moodstocks-phonegap-plugin/issues/17) also.

Can we ignore this thread warning or is it related to memory issue in iOS Phone-gap

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run cordova plugins in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382260/how-to-run-cordova-plugins-in-the-background)

Comment: @Callodacity, My question regarding to solve the warning message while using plugins in background, but not how to run cordova plugins in background

Comment: okay no worries, I was just checking 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/issue-in-iphone-using-jquery-mobile-resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-#mhabK7SbHUefPmNonZJHVg). solved my warning issue

I found warning can be ignored .But this can be solved by adding background thread using this loop:(In CDVLogger.m)

```
 [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{

    //add your code here
 }
```

Now this looks as below for console warning:

```
- (void)logLevel:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
 {
   [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
   id level = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
   id message = [command argumentAtIndex:1];

  if ([level isEqualToString:@"LOG"]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", message);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"%@: %@", level, message);
   }
 }];
}
```

Comment: Similarly  the warning can be solved for camera ,geolocation,pushplugin etc "[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{//code here
 }"

Comment: this only restricts log from being printed on main thread. This one just pulls the message to background thread, but does not solve the actual problem of the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Also to add,

If someone is looking for a way to run sepcifically the Geolocation plugin as a background thread with iOS Cordova there is a fix on GitHub.

It removes the Xcode output warning: "THREAD WARNING: ['Geolocation'] took 'X' ms. Plugin should use a background thread."

Download the plugin from here: 
https://github.com/guillaumedev/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Heres whats changed (runInBackground added): 
https://github.com/guillaumedev/cordova-plugin-geolocation/commit/8fbceca845441f4f421548f243d2f05573d11225

More information about Cordova Threading: 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html#threading