# Ionic Cordova app crashes at launch in ipad

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I checked it in many devices, in almost all it is working without any issue. But when checked in iPad with OS version 9.3.5, first time launch causes crash. i have no idea why it is crashing. I have checked a lot for the solution, but couldn't find any. The log from XCode when running is

> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.334 [10543:4215404] DiskCookieStorage changing
>   policy from 2 to 0, cookie file:
>   file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C264816D-2744-4D26-BC6A-46B3BEF8DA46/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.498[10543:4215404] Apache Cordova native platform
>   version 4.0.0 is starting.
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.501[10543:4215404] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES,
>   App: YES
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.676[10543:4215404] Using UIWebView
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.684[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl]
>   0.398993ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.692[10543:4215404]
>   [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 8.102000ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.693[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler]
>   0.422001ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.736[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][splashscreen]
>   42.403996ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.764[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][statusbar]
>   27.370989ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.769[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 3.852963ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.772[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][localnotification]
>   2.893984ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.773[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][localnotification]
>   0.070989ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:12.773[10543:4215404] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup]
>   89.882970ms
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:13.556[10543:4215404] Resetting plugins due to page
>   load.
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:15.216[10543:4215404] Finished load of:
>   file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2B7D0DC-8697-4605-B0FC-B72CA832E4F3/appName.app/www/index.html
>
> 2017-07-03 11:58:16.653[10543:4215404] THREAD WARNING: ['Device'] took
>   '15.490967' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

I know it shows a thread warning, but they say it can be neglected [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/issue-in-iphone-using-jquery-mobile-resetting-plugins-due-to-page-load-#mhabK7SbHUefPmNonZJHVg)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30433453/7456236) stack overflow answer also to remove the warning. But that too couldn't fix the issue. My Cordova version is 6.5.0.

Comment: Have you tried to check the console logs in chrome when the app opens up.?

Comment: @scary_devil Yes. I have. Since i  run in chrome, it shows status bar error & icon error. No other error is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10530?focusedCommentId=15149506&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15149506) post, at last I solved it. Removed old ios platform & updated it with the new. Now its working without any issue