# Adding runInBackground for CDVPluginResult gives new error "failed to return after 10 seconds"

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, background-service

I am using cordova plugin https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer plugin for iOS 9. But it gave me error "Plugin should use a background thread.".

So I introduced "[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{}]" code in .m file as per suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22400699/1554456, but this gives me new error.

void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Can you suggest how to tweak the plugin to support iOS 9, and make background alarm work.

Answer (score 0):

It will work Fine.
open your projectname.xcodeproj file.

Goto project Navigator --> Click on target -->Select Capabilities -->Background mode (trun ON)
Also add selected add-on Keys on info.plist file

Comment: I checked all services, even though I don't know which ones will be suitable to me, to just get callback of the plugin work, and even xcode automatically added them into plist, but still I don't see logs in console.